# Remove an element of a collection by a FormType

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony-3.4

I am using Symfony 3.4.7 . I work with 3 linked entites, Articles, Categories, an ArticlesCategories. ArticlesCategories is the relation table.

To manage an article and their relation articleCategories, I use the class CollectionType that I add to the FormType ArticlesType.

In my display I add and I remove a relation articlesCatégroies to an Article.

This is the code of an entity Articles :

```
/**
* Articles
*
* @ORM\Table(name="articles")
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticlesRepository")
* @UniqueEntity("codeArticle", message="Déjà utilisé")
*/
class Articles
{

public function __construct()
{
    $this->articlesCategories = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="code_article", type="string", length=10)
 * @ORM\Id
 */
private $codeArticle;

//... other variables

/**
 * @var ArticlesCategories
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ArticlesCategories", mappedBy="codeArticle", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $articlesCategories;

// other getters and setters 

/**
 * Add articlesCategorie
 *
 * @param ArticlesCategories $articleCategorie
 *
 * @return Articles
 */
public function addArticlesCategorie(ArticlesCategories $articleCategorie){
    $this->articlesCategories[] = $articleCategorie;
    $articleCategorie->setCodeArticle($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * remove articlesCategorie
 *
 * @param ArticlesCategories $articlesCategorie
 */
public function removeArticlesCategorie(ArticlesCategories $articlesCategorie){
    $this->articlesCategories->removeElement($articlesCategorie);
}

public function setArticlesCategories($articlesCategories){
    $this->articlesCategories = $articlesCategories;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get articlesCategories
 *
 * @return Collection
 */
public function getArticlesCategories(){
    return $this->articlesCategories;
}
}
```

This the code of an entity ArticlesCategories :

```
/**
 * ArticlesCategories
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="articles_categories", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_codeArticle_codeCategorie", columns={"code_article_id", "code_categorie_id"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ArticlesCategoriesRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"codeArticle", "codeCategorie"}, message="Cette relation est déjà enregistré")
 */
class ArticlesCategories
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Articles", inversedBy="articlesCategories", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="code_article", nullable=false)
     */
    private $codeArticle;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Categories", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="reference", nullable=false)
     */
    private $codeCategorie;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="critere_rech_1", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $critereRech1;

    //... getters and setters
}
```

This is the code of my form ArticlesType :

```
class ArticlesType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('codeArticle')
            //...autres attributs
            ->add('articlesCategories', CollectionType::class, array(
                'entry_type' => ArticlesCategoriesType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype' => true,
                'label' => 'categories',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'collection-articlesCategories'),
                'auto_initialize' => true,
                'by_reference' => false
            ));
    }
}
```

This the action who I called when I want to edit an article :

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing article entity.
     *
     * @Route("/edit/{codeArticle}", name="articles_edit", defaults={"codeArticle" = null} )
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     */
    public function editAction(Request $request, Articles $article = null)
    {
        if($article != null){
            /*$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $article = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Articles')->find($id_article);*/
            $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($article);
            $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ArticlesType', $article);
            $editForm->handleRequest($request);

            if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
                // récupère tous les articles même ceux qui viennent d'être ajouter par la fonction JS add
                $articlesCategories = $article->getArticlesCategories();
                dump($articlesCategories);
                foreach($articlesCategories as $ac){
                    // si l'article est null
                    if($ac->getCodeArticle() == null){
                        // on attribue à la relation articleCategorie l'article que l'on modifi
                        $ac->setCodeArticle($article);
                    }

                }
                $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            }

            return $this->render('articles/edit.html.twig', array(
                'article' => $article,
                'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
                'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
            ));
        }
        else{
            return $this->forward('AppBundle:articles:new', [
                    'message' => 'Pour éditer un article il faut d\'abord l\'afficher.'
                ]
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I display the form on the Twig view.
And I use Jquery to add and remove of the form a relation ArticlesCategories. 
This is what the form of my article looks like with its collection:
[My display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWWoB.jpg)
The probleme that I meet is, when i add a relation and I click on "Editer", I can see that the relation is create in my database. But when I remove a relation and I click on "Editer", I can see that my relation is not remove on the database.

I don't see where is my mistake.

I hope I am clear. 
Thank you for help.

[EDIT]
This is my view twig :

```
    {% extends 'articles/gerer.html.twig' %}
{% import 'articles/fields.html.twig' as formMacros %}

{% block contenu %}
    {{ form_start(delete_form) }}
    <input type="submit" value="Supprimer">
    {{ form_end(delete_form) }}

    {{ form_start(edit_form) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.codeArticle, "Référence article") }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.codeArticle) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.codeArticle, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.description, "Description") }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.description) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.description, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.ecotaxe) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.ecotaxe) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.ecotaxe, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.qteMaxCde) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.qteMaxCde) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.qteMaxCde, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.publication) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.publication) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.publication, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.designation) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.designation) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.designation, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.taxonomie) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.taxonomie) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.taxonomie, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.referenceStock) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.referenceStock) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.referenceStock, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.articleRegroupement) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.articleRegroupement) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.articleRegroupement, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.articleAssocie1) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.articleAssocie1) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.articleAssocie1, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.articleAssocie2) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.articleAssocie2) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.articleAssocie2, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.articleAssocie3) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.articleAssocie3) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.articleAssocie3, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.seuilDegressif) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.seuilDegressif) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.seuilDegressif, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

        {{ form_label(edit_form.tauxDegressif) }}
        {{ form_errors(edit_form.tauxDegressif) }}
        {{ form_widget(edit_form.tauxDegressif, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}

    <div class="row well well-sm js-collection-articles-categories-wrapper" data-prototype="{{ formMacros.printCategorieRow(edit_form.articlesCategories.vars.prototype)|e('html_attr') }}"
         data-index="{{ edit_form.articlesCategories|length }}">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            Catégories
        </div>
        {% for ac in  edit_form.articlesCategories %}
            {{ formMacros.printCategorieRow(ac) }}
        {% endfor %}
        <a href="#" class="js-collection-articles-categories-add">
            <span class="fa fa-plus-circle"> Ajouter une catégorie</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Modifier" />

    {{ form_end(edit_form) }}
{% endblock %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        var $wrapper = $('.js-collection-articles-categories-wrapper');

        $wrapper.on('click', '.js-remove-articles-categories', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $(this).closest('.js-collection-articles-categories-item')
                .fadeOut()
                .remove();
        })

        $wrapper.on('click', '.js-collection-articles-categories-add', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var prototype = $wrapper.data('prototype');

            var index = $wrapper.data('index');

            var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

            $wrapper.data('index', index + 1);

            $(this).before(newForm);
        })
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I use a form_theme to display an element of my collection, this is the code :

```
{% import _self as formMacros %}
    {% macro printCategorieRow(ac) %}
        <div class="js-collection-articles-categories-item">

            {{ form_errors(ac) }}
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-6">
                {{ form_label(ac.codeCategorie) }}
                {{ form_widget(ac.codeCategorie, {'attr': {'class': 'select_articles_categories'}}) }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                <a href="#" class="js-remove-articles-categories pull-right">
                    <span class="fa fa-close">Supprimer une catégorie</span>
                </a>
                <table class="table">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Critères</th>
                        <th>Valeurs</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="new_article_table_critere1">
                        <td><div id="critere1">{{ form_label(ac.critereRech1) }}</div></td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(ac.critereRech1, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="new_article_table_critere2">
                        <td><div id="critere2">{{ form_label(ac.critereRech2) }}</div></td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(ac.critereRech2, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="new_article_table_critere3">
                        <td><div id="critere3">{{ form_label(ac.critereRech3) }}</div></td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(ac.critereRech3, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="new_article_table_critere4">
                        <td><div id="critere4">{{ form_label(ac.critereRech4) }}</div></td>
                        <td>{{ form_widget(ac.critereRech4, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}
```

Comment: If you put the following `onDelete="CASCADE"` into both @JoinColumn attributes in your ArticlesCategories class does it work ?

Comment: I tried to put `onDelete="CASCADE"` on the class ArticlesCategories and it doesn't work.
This the code for the attribute articlesCategories in the entity Articles :

Comment: `/**
     * @var ArticlesCategories
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ArticlesCategories", mappedBy="codeArticle", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $articlesCategories;`
and the code for an article in the entity ArticlesCategories :

`/**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Articles", inversedBy="articlesCategories")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="code_article", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
    private $codeArticle;`

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change in your entity, 'Articles'.

Note: Don't forget to add a setter function (ex: setcodeArticle()) for 'codeArticle' in your entity, 'ArticlesCategories'

```
public function removeArticlesCategorie(ArticlesCategories $articlesCategorie){
    $this->articlesCategories->removeElement($articlesCategorie);
    $articlesCategorie->setcodeArticle(null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you to your answer, I add this code but it doesn't work. Maybe this function is not called. But I don't know how to see that.

Comment: Can you please show me your twig template, including the JQuery part

Comment: I edit my post and I put the code inside the post. Thank's !

Comment: Inside the tag, <a> write href and class in this order ->  <a class="js-remove-articles-categories pull-right"  href="#" >

Comment: $wrapper.on('click', '.js-remove-articles-categories', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("This is working");
            $(this).closest('.js-collection-articles-categories-item')
                .fadeOut()
                .remove();
        })

Also check whether you are able to enter in to the remove function by writing an alert message like above

Comment: I don't think that you understand what it doesn't work. 
This jquery work. In the display the relation articlesCategories is remove. My problem is in Database, this relation is not remove in the database.